# Segmentation Fault with strcat char* allocated

Tags: c

The memory allocation is somewhat complicated for the newer users to C, I have read the other answers regarding this topic, but I have not managed to understand them completely so I ask again something that perhaps is redundant.

My problem is that I receive a Segmentation fault in the line, the idea is to convert a decimal number to binary, the result in the form of a string, that is, for example 27 = "11011", I use a char array to which I want to concatenate the results of the modular operation number% 2 in the form of char.

I would also appreciate information on how to solve these types of problems that have been very common to me lately.

```
int main()
{
    char *numero_bin = malloc(256 * sizeof(int));
    long numero = 1;

    char auxiliar;

    memset(numero_bin, 0, sizeof numero_bin);
    numero_bin[0] = '\0';
    while (numero != 0)
    {
        scanf("%d", &numero);
        if (numero == 0)
            break;

        for (int i = 0; numero > 0; i++)
        {
            //numero_bin[i] = (char)numero % 2;
            auxiliar = numero % 2;
            strcat(numero_bin, auxiliar);
            numero = numero / 2;
        }
        numero = 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The [`strcat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) functions wants two null-terminated strings as arguments.

Comment: `sizeof numero_bin` will give you the size of a pointer.

Comment: you don't need malloc here. Use char numero_bin[256*sizeof(int)]={0}. The array is immediately filled with 0. no memset required.

Comment: and use strncat iso strcat with code like this.

Comment: By the way, you never "clear" `numero_bin` in the loop, it will grow and grow and grow... All until you go out of bounds and again have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are passing char to `strcat` it takes `char *` man page [strcat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html)

```
   strcat(numero_bin, auxiliar);
```

change the `auxiliar` to `&auxiliar` and use `strncat` instead

---

There is a second problem that is assigning invalid values to `auxiliar`
which is here

```
auxiliar = numero % 2;
```

this merely assigns integer 0 or 1 what exactly you need is `'0'` or `'1'`
change this to

```
auxiliar = numero % 2 + '0';
```

now to the Long story ..

from manual, it says strcat appends `copy of null-terminated string`

> char *
> strcat(char *restrict s1, const char *restrict s2);
>
> The strcat() and strncat() functions append a copy of the
> null-terminated string s2 to the end of the null-terminated string s1,
> then
> add a terminating `\0'.  The string s1 must have sufficient space to hold the result.

now the function call

```
strcat(numero_bin, &auxiliar);
```

here `auxiliar` is defined as a char and this `&auxiliar` points to memory wherever it is defined

```
auxiliar  +------+ - - - +- 
          |.     |       | <- we do not know what is here; may be null may not be
          +------+ - - - +-
           0x01    0x02
      &auxiliar
```

now when the function above is executes, strcat tries to copy and concatenate .. it keeps taking characters starting at location `&auxiliar` and `&auxiliar + 1` and so on till it encounters `'\0'`

because we have not specified the length this will induce something called Undefined behaviour..

how do we fix this .. instead of sending `&auxiliar` to `strcat` we can use strncat and say copy only one character for example

```
strncat(numero_bin, &auxiliar, 1);
```

or we can still use `strcat` do something like this

```
for (int i = 0; numero > 0; i++)
{
    auxiliar = (numero % 2) + '0';
    char b[2] ;
         b[0] = auxiliar;
         b[1] = '\0'; // b is '\0' terminated for sure
    strcat(numero_bin, b);
    numero = numero / 2;
}
```

More information from manual

> ECURITY CONSIDERATIONS
> The strcat() function is easily misused in a manner which enables malicious users to arbitrarily change a running program's functional-
> ity through a buffer overflow attack.  (See the FSA.)
>
> Avoid using strcat().  Instead, use strncat() or strlcat() and ensure that no more characters are copied to the destination buffer
> than
> it can hold.
>
> Note that strncat() can also be problematic.  It may be a security concern for a string to be truncated at all.  Since the
> truncated
> string will not be as long as the original, it may refer to a completely different resource and usage of the truncated resource
> could
> result in very incorrect behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i've implemented the & operator and now i dont have the segmentation fault, but im not having the expected result, my first char* numero_bin now is 0xaa1590 "\001\021\001\001" i expected to be somthing like ¨110011¨

Answer (score 0):

strcat() takes 2 strings (basically 2 character arrays which are null terminated) as arguments and appends the second string to the first one.

You have declared variable auxiliar as a char. A single character is not a string in C. So passing the character as an argument which expects a string (null terminated char array) will generate an error. To resolve this you have to pass the address of the char(&auxiliar) as the second argument.